# Awaiting the same method (passed as a parameter) twice

Tags: flutter, async-await, future

I'm trying to write a method inside a package I'm currently developing but I got stuck trying to await the same method a second time.

This is the pseudo code for my method:

```
Future<MyResultClass> ErrorHandlingMethod(Future<MyResultClass> MyMethod) async {
  
  MyResultClass result = await MyMethod;

  (if result.failed && result.cause.canBeFixed){
     ...
     ...
     // Do something that may cause MyMethod to complete successfully
     ...
     ...
     result = await MyMethod;
  }

  return result;
}
```

MyMethod (a DIO request with a bunch of interceptors) completes but the server returns an error code, now in some cases I can fix whatever caused the problem so after doing that I want to make the same call again and return the new result.

The problem is the second time I'm awaiting MyMethod it returns the result I got the first time without making a new DIO request.

The real code is a little more complicated than this but this is the main problem I'm having right now.

Does anyone know how can I force MyMethod to be actually executed again?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think it should be `Future<MyResultClass> ErrorHandlingMethod(Future<MyResultClass> MyMethod)async{`

Comment: yes it's actually like that, I forgot the async in the pseudo code, I'm going to fix it now

Comment: Can you include what are you passing on `ErrorHandlingMethod`

Comment: Another method of my library (it can be one of many), something like MyPackageMethod('param1', param2) all these methods return a MyResultClass object, bur the number of parameters can be different from method to method.

Comment: It is still calling the same method with same return value in my case,  I think because we are feeding the same object

Comment: I guess so, since it's trying to await something that has already been awaited.